# Plotting graphs in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a pseudo color graph with python but it keeps crashing. There is a rocket dancing but nothing more happens.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl

coef = np.load('corrcoef.npz') #22277 x 22277

pl.pcolor(coef)
pl.colorbar()
pl.show()
```

It plots the graph for smaller matrices. It works fine on other computers so I am not sure if this is my fault or the computer's. It is a mac with 8Gb of Ram. When I try to run it on a Linux machine with the same amount of ram i get a MemoryError

Comment: If that was a matrix of `uint8_t`, it would still be over 470MB.  I'm not surprised `pylab` is complaining.  Try saving it straight to file (not using show) if you just want to see the figure.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython)

Comment: I tried but I still get the dancing rocket with no output

Comment: Actually now I don't get the rocket but the program doesn't terminates and it makes the computer slow

Comment: I'd say you're giving it too much data, then.  It's not clear what `corrcoef.npz` actually contains, but if it were, say, longs, you're asking pylab to plot ~1.9GB of data at once.

Comment: Yeah i need it to plot everything at once. it is a 4Gb file with floats. On other computers it works fine and i don't understand why it crashed on this one

Comment: I doubt you need all that data - there sure as hell aren't 4 gigapixels in the final figure.  Preprocess it.

Comment: Haven't you already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525963/python-and-matplotlib-on-mac)?

Comment: Closed? This is a real question, and the one everyone says is a duplicate is not a question, so it doesn't make sense for this to be a duplicate.  It's similar, but the OP, has restated this one so it's clear: this code works with small data but not large data, what can I do?  Restating the question clearly is what we want people to do when a question is closed, and now the OP is being punished for that.

Answer (score 2):

Due to physical limitations both of your hardware and your brain, you can't analyze large data sets exactly like you would small ones, so it's necessary to rethink your process a bit.

You say you need to plot every pixel of a 22,300 x 22,300 array, but no screen will show this and your nervous system could never take in all in anyway.  Say it takes your nervous system 0.01 sec to observe each pixel (which is probably an underestimate), it would take you 57 days to observe this data the way you suggest you need to.

Instead, think about what you want to know about the data and find a way to get at this without plotting the entire thing.  Some simple examples of how to do this would be to average neighboring cells, or look for extrema (max and min), etc.  Doing this over 100x100 grids will make your final plot 223x223 which is easily manageable.