# Is there any way to ask Basemap not show the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, show, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to use mpl_toolkits.basemap on python and everytime I use a function for plotting like drawcoastlines() or any other, the program automatically shows the plot on the screen.

My problem is that I am trying to use those programs later on an external server and it returns 'SystemExit: Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?'

Is there any way I can avoid the plot to be shown when I use a Basemap function on it?
I just want to save it to a file so later I can read it externally.

My code is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines()

#m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,10.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.))
```

Comment: What python shell are you using? I suspect you are using iPython? When I run your code with a cPython (i.e. `python`) shell it doesn't show the figures unless I call `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` (or something equivalent).

Comment: yes, I am using ipython, but I when I use   python filename.py   in my computer's console the graph does not appear but if I do that on the server console it returns me the same error.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting interactive mode off, ie `plt.ioff()`? Or have you tried explicitly using a non-interactive backend, ie supplying one of the strings in `matplotlib.rcsetup.non_interactive_bk` to `matplotlib.use`?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Agg` backend, it doesn't require a graphical environment:

Do this at the very beginning of your script:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
```

See also the FAQ on [Generate images without having a window appear](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put off the interactive mode of matplotlib.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#NOT SHOW
plt.ioff()

m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0)
m.drawcoastlines()

#m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,10.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,360.,60.))
```