# Julia: How to save a figure without plotting/displaying it in PyPlot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia, figure

I am using the PyPlot package in Julia to generate and save several figures. My current approach is to display the figure and then save it using `savefig`.

```
using PyPlot
a = rand(50,40)
imshow(a)
savefig("a.png")
```

Is there a way to save the figure without having to first display it?

Comment: If you can sort out how to control the mpl backend, set it to `'Agg'`.

Comment: At a minimum, you can set the backend in your `.matplotlibrc` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the REPL or IJulia?

If you close the figure then it won't show you the plot. Is that what you want?

```
a = rand(50,40)
ioff() #turns off interactive plotting
fig = figure()
imshow(a)
close(fig)
```

If that doesn't work you might need to turn off interactive plotting using `ioff()` or change the matplotlib backend (`pygui(:Agg)`) (see here: [Calling pylab.savefig without display in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython))

Remember that most questions about plotting using PyPlot can be worked out by reading answers from the python community. And also using the docs at https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl to translate between the two :)

Answer (score 1):

close() doesn't require any arguments so you can just call close() after saving the figure and create a new figure

```
using PyPlot
a = rand(50,40)
imshow(a)
savefig("a.png")
# call close
close()
```