# Python: How to show matplotlib in flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I'm very new to Flask and Matplotlib.  I'd like to be able to show a simple chart I generated in some html, but I'm having a very hard time figuring out how.  Here is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import numpy as np
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)
variables = pandas.read_csv('C:\\path\\to\\variable.csv')
price =variables['price']


@app.route('/test')
def chartTest():
    lnprice=np.log(price)
    plt.plot(lnprice)
    return render_template('untitled1.html', name = plt.show())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h1>Price Chart</h1>

      <p>{{ name }}</p>

      <img src={{ name }} alt="Chart" height="42" width="42">

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not simply work that way, you will need to save the plot as an image/vector first (either to disk or store in memory) so it can be loaded in the browser. This involves a few more things, but you can get started looking at how to save it first here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931148/9802392 and then check how to  serve it from Flask here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask

Comment: Thank you, I'll get right to reading through those.

Comment: Comment here if you get stuck, ideally showing some progress of what you have tried in the question, serving a file from Flask has several solutions and is prerequisite that your html can show/reach that file. Your html is not necessarily wrong completely, you cannot just pass a Python object to the view, so what you pass as {{ name }} should be a URL. And you want that to be in "" too. Hope you succeed.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can generate the image on-the-fly in Flask URL route handler:

```
import io
import random
from flask import Response
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot_png():
    fig = create_figure()
    output = io.BytesIO()
    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
    return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

def create_figure():
    fig = Figure()
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    xs = range(100)
    ys = [random.randint(1, 50) for x in xs]
    axis.plot(xs, ys)
    return fig
```

Then you need to include the image in your HTML template:

```
<img src="/plot.png" alt="my plot">
```

Comment: This won't show changing dynamic plot content reliably due to browser caching. For static plots that won't change on reload, this is fine

Comment: You can (and should, if the data are dynamic) add appropriate http headers to disable caching. Ultimately, if you need the data to be “realtime”, you should choose different approach – feed the data to the browser via websocket and plot them using JavaScript (d3.js or similar).

Comment: I am trying to adapt `plot_png()` to receive arguments *xs, ys* but there is a `TypeError: plot_png() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'xs' and 'ys'`. I just pasted the same random generated samples in the `main()` instead of inside the `create_figure()`. What's wrong?

Comment: A flask app might be called from uwsgi using multiple threads. Is the above usage of matplotlib thread-safe?

Comment: is there a way to change png with a gif using a similar method?

Comment: Doesn't work for me as of Flask 1.1.2

Comment: @KrisStern This didn't work for me initially either, using flask 2.0.1. But I changed line 5 from `from matplotlib.figure import Figure` to `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`. After that I removed the first line of `plot_png` and changed the line before the return to `FigureCanvas(plt.gcf()).print_png(output)`. Worked like a dream.

Answer (score 10):

As @d parolin pointed out, the figure generated by `matplotlib` will need to be saved before being rendered by the HTML. In order to serve images in `flask` by HTML, you will need to store the image in your `flask` file directory:

```
static/
  images/
    plot.png --> store plots here
templates/
```

Therefore, in your application, use `plt.savefig`:

```
@app.route('/test')
def chartTest():
  lnprice=np.log(price)
  plt.plot(lnprice)   
  plt.savefig('/static/images/new_plot.png')
  return render_template('untitled1.html', name = 'new_plot', url ='/static/images/new_plot.png')
```

Then in `untitled1.html`:

```
  <p>{{ name }}</p>

  <img src={{ url}} alt="Chart" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: There is no need to save the image. In order to display it in HTML you can put the data directly into src argument of img tag.

Comment: @MaciekS This sounds like a good idea. Please show a code example.

Comment: @mac13k It is difficult to put the code here, so I shared it as a [GitLab snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1924163).

Comment: If anyone reading this gets `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, avoid using Matplotlib GUI. This is done by importing the `Agg` - see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15713545/13055097