# How to run matplotlib plot on a flask server

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask

I am very new to python. I just want to know Is there any way to insert matplotlib plot on a web page using flask, without converting to static JPG or png?

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    x = [2, 4, 6]
    y = [1, 3, 5]
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is what I expect as an output:
[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z452.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[This question has been asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728328/python-how-to-show-matplotlib-in-flask)

While that answer will do what you want, I can't help but to tell you I think you are using the wrong tool. I suggest looking into [Plotly's Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) or [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) as those packages are actually meant for rendering data visualizations in a web browser with Python.