# How to stream a data from ms-sql server at an interval of 10 mins into jupyter notebook and plot it

Tags: sql-server, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook which has a connection to my ms-sql DB. After doing some analysis I plot some graph using matplotlib. Now I want to stream the data at an interval of every 10 min which is loaded in the jupyter notebook and  stored in a Dataframe and plot the graph from it and then share the interactive graph as dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a need to stay in Jupyter Notebook?
Maybe better done using Flask, but your viewers don't see the code that's being used...

Comment: Hi, can you share any examples of how this can be done on flask, as it is not necessary to show the code to the viewers.

Comment: There are a few examples [Show Matplotlib in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728328/python-how-to-show-matplotlib-in-flask) or perhaps plotly [Flask + Plotly Dashboard](https://blog.heptanalytics.com/2018/08/07/flask-plotly-dashboard/) but its just not in the interactive style of Jupyter Notebook