# why I cant return my plot graph in flask python

Tags: python, flask

I need some help, the situation is I m able to return the new CSV file but unable to return the plot graph to another page, and I did separate the `return` under different scenarios. Does anyone can point out what should I do to my code? or perhaps give me some tips, Thanks in advance!

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files['data_file']:
            f = request.files['data_file']
            if not f:
                return "No file"
    
            
            stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
            csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
            stream.seek(0)
            result = stream.read()
            df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result), usecols=[1])
            
            #extract month value
            df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result))
            matrix2 = df2[df2.columns[0]].to_numpy()
            list1 = matrix2.tolist()
             
            # load the model from disk
            model = load_model('model.h5')
            dataset = df.values
            dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
            scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
            dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
            look_back = 1
            dataset_look = create_dataset(dataset, look_back)
            dataset_look = np.reshape(dataset_look, (dataset_look.shape[0], 1, dataset_look.shape[1]))
            predict = model.predict(dataset_look)
            transform = scaler.inverse_transform(predict)
    
            X_FUTURE = 12
            transform = np.array([])
            last = dataset[-1]
            for i in range(X_FUTURE):
                curr_prediction = model.predict(np.array([last]).reshape(1, look_back, 1))
                last = np.concatenate([last[1:], curr_prediction.reshape(-1)])
                transform = np.concatenate([transform, curr_prediction[0]])
          
            transform = scaler.inverse_transform([transform])[0]
    
            dicts = []
            curr_date = pd.to_datetime(list1[-1])
            for i in range(X_FUTURE):
                curr_date = curr_date +  relativedelta(months=+1)
                dicts.append({'Predictions': transform[i], "Month": curr_date})
    
    
            new_data = pd.DataFrame(dicts).set_index("Month")
            ##df_predict = pd.DataFrame(transform, columns=["predicted value"])
    
                          
        
            response = make_response(new_data.to_csv(index = True, encoding='utf8'))
            response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
            return response
        
            labels = [
                        'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR',
                        'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG',
                        'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'
                       ]
    
            values = [
                            967.67, 1190.89, 1079.75, 1349.19,
                            2328.91, 2504.28, 2873.83, 4764.87,
                            4349.29, 6458.30, 9907, 16297
                        ]
    
            colors = [
                            "#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#FEDCBA",
                            "#ABCDEF", "#DDDDDD", "#ABCABC", "#4169E1",
                            "#C71585", "#FF4500", "#FEDCBA", "#46BFBD"]
            return redirect(url_for('line'))
    
    @app.route('/line')
    def line():
        line_labels=labels
        line_values=values
        return render_template('graph.html', title='Bitcoin Monthly Price in USD', max=17000, labels=line_labels, values=line_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to save it first to specific folder and then in frontend you can specify the image like that you pass it in url

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
     
plt.savefig('path/plot.png')
```

or else you can use JavaScript to render graph to frontend you can use chart.js etc.

Comment: Hi @Bhavya, Thanks for commenting, I did try to add `plt.savefig('path/plot.png')` and it actually does not work, the problem is it dint return `render_template` at all, and can you demo like how to plot graph using chart.js as you said ?

Comment: Hey you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728328/python-how-to-show-matplotlib-in-flask from here! and for chart.js you can go through official document as well as from stack overflow it self you can find your answer just try diff. methods.

Comment: I think `chartjs` also not work because it has to `return render_template` also, my problem is the second `return` cannot work at all

Comment: I have edited another version for you to see my problem, I cant return my `return redirect(url_for('line'))`, Please help ~

Comment: your code is not as with proper indentation required in python see that first if condition please update the code

Comment: Updated ~ please have a look

Comment: last return statement is correct with indentation??

Comment: yaya , I have try remove the entire predicted code and just leave the plot graph code, and its able to return the graph as normally

Comment: thats great!! now you can debug that prediction code or else use redirect also there if you want to.

Comment: but when I come to combine the prediction code and plot graph code together, It literally cannot return these 2 combined codes together. For the plot graph, actually I wanted to put the `predicted value` as Y-axis and `month` as X-axis. However, I have to solve the return problem which only I can adjust the x-axis and y-axis. The previous I mentioned when I remove the predicted code then the plot graph works, is I want to clarify that there is no problem with the plot graph code, The problem is when the `predicted code` and `plot graph` come together, Its only can return the `predicted code `.