# Programmatically making and saving plots in (I)python without rendering them on the screen first

Tags: python, graphics, ipython, spyder

Here's a dummy script that makes three plots and saves them to PDF.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.random.normal(100),
                   "B":np.random.chisquare(5, size = 100),
                   "C":np.random.gamma(5,size = 100)})

for i in df.columns:
    plt.hist(df[i])
    plt.savefig(i+".pdf", format = "pdf")
    plt.close()
```

I'm using spyder, which uses IPython.  When I run this script, three windows pop at me and then go away.  It works, but it's a little annoying.

How can I make the figures get saved to pdf without ever being rendered on my screen?

I'm looking for something like R's

```
pdf("path/to/plot/name.pdf")
commands
dev.off()
```

inasmuch as nothing gets rendered on the screen, but the pdf gets saved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython

Answer (score 2):

Aha.  Partially based on the duplicate suggestion (which wasn't exactly a duplicate), this works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":np.random.normal(100),
                   "B":np.random.chisquare(5, size = 100),
                   "C":np.random.gamma(5,size = 100)})

import matplotlib
old_backend = matplotlib.get_backend()
matplotlib.use("pdf")

for i in df.columns:
    plt.hist(df[i])
    plt.savefig(i+".pdf", format = "pdf")
    plt.close()

matplotlib.use(old_backend)
```

Basically, set the backend to something like a pdf device, and then set it back to whatever you're accustomed to.

Answer (score 1):

I am referring you to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib/9890599) which cites this [article](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear) as an answer. In the SO answer they also suggest `plt.ioff()` but are concerned that it could disable other functionality should you want it.