# Disable display using corner.py on a remote machine using ssh

Tags: python, ssh, display

I have been creating plots on a remote machine using ssh. When I use matplotlib, I can save the figures and avoid displaying them by using `matplotlib.use("PDF")`. I am now creating a plot using corner.py [API](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), but I cannot figure out a similar way to avoid displaying the figure. (I am not explicitly requesting to show the figure anywhere.)

The error can be recreated by:

```
import corner
import numpy as np

# Random data
ndim, nsamples = 3, 1000
np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim])

# Make figure
figure = corner.corner(samples)
figure.savefig('test.pdf')
```

My first error was

> _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.

I tried adding `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` to my .bashrc file, but then got

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0".

I have tried `figure.ioff(), plt.close(figure)`, and using `ssh -X remoteMachine` but I keep getting similar errors.

I don't need or want to display the figure, I just want to save it.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can run `xvfb` and set DISPLAY to its screen as per [Setting DISPLAY variable with Xvfb - CentOS](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47435). But without a [mcve], I cannot test that for your particular case.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have now added an example that shows what gives me the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling pylab.savefig without display in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython)

Comment: As their suggestion is to use matplotlib.use('Agg'), which I understand to be similar to me using matplotlib.use('PDF'), do you know how this would translate to using corner instead of matplotlib?

Comment: [AFAICS, `PDF` is a renderer, not a backend.](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`corner` uses `matplotlib` as backend](https://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#corner-py), so the answer from [Calling pylab.savefig without display in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython) applies here -- select a `matplotlib` backend that renders in memory:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import corner
<etc>
```

Note the order: `matplotlib` requires `.use()` to be called before `matplotlib.pyplot` or other plotting-related modules are imported for the first time; otherwise, it has no effect and a `UserWarning` is printed explaining this. [`corner.corner` module imports `pyplot` right upon its import.](https://github.com/dfm/corner.py/blob/master/corner/corner.py#L7)